# Heroku telegam python bot deploy

Tags: python, heroku, telegram

My python telegram bot code is

```
import telebot, os
from telebot import types
# from telebot import
from settings import TOKEN
import requests
#from pyTelegramBotAPI import users
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
import sqlite3
import json

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(text="Дати доступ до гуолокації.", request_location=True))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нам потрібена ваша геолокація", reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling()
```

And Proc file is `web: python bot.py`

When I run it local **bot is working**, after deploy **bot send nothing to user**

Answer (score 1):

You have to upload 3 files to Heroku:

**Proc**

```
web: python bot.py
```

**requirements.txt**

```
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.6.6
heroku==0.1.4
```

+ other moduls

**runtime.txt**

```
python-3.7.0
```

or other python version

And I recommend to replaсe `bot.polling()` with `bot.infinity_polling(True)`